# Monitoring GitHub workflow via Grafana

Tags: github, github-actions, grafana, monitoring

I want to monitor GitHub with Grafana and I came across https://github.com/grafana/github-datasource which can do the trick.
Have added the data source as `cm` and added it as plugin in grafana deployment but my deployment fails saying it can't find the plugin

```
Error: ✗ grafana-github-datasource either does not exist or is not supported on your system (Grafana v8.4.7 linux-amd64)
```

My configmap looks as below:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  github.yaml: |-
    apiVersion: v1
    datasources:
      - access: proxy
        name: GitHub
        type: grafana-github-datasource
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2023-03-01T21:26:19Z"
  name: github-datasource
  namespace: kube-prometheus-stack
  resourceVersion: "176513298"
  uid: 22d3a597-119f-48f9-970d-605bc258f135
```

Monitor Github workflow with grafana

Comment: It also says that it might not be supported by your machine, are you sure that it's not the case?

Comment: yes thats correct according to  https://github.com/grafana/github-datasource/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#110---next 

Now I am getting another error because of datasource config
`lvl=warn msg="invalid access value, will use 'proxy' instead" value=server
`

Comment: This plugin doesn't has workflow actions added.. #grafana